# How to handle Firestore write limits and index exemptions for subcollections?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following schema for my Firestore database:

```
[collection]
<document>

[chats]
    <user123>
        [userChats]
            <user789>
            <user345>
            <user567>
    <user789>
        [userChats]
            <user123>
            <user345>
            <user567>
```

In the `userChats` subcollection, the documents contain a sequentially-incremented field that is indexed. A sequentially-incremented indexed field imposes a write limit on that collection. Is this limit applied to each subcollection individually? Or is it imposed on all of the `userChats` subcollections as if they were one since they share the same name?

Furthermore, assume the documents in the `userChats` subcollection have a `private` field that I wish to add as a single-field index exemption. What scope would I need to add this exemption, collection or collection-group? And if I choose collection-group, would it have any impact on the write limit mentioned above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database doesn't so much impose a limit, as that your choice to use sequential values leads to a hotspot when updating the index for that field. The database simply physically can only write values close to each other (while meeting the cross-datacenter requirements and consistency guarantees of Firestore) at a certain speed, which is why it's best to avoid sequences when possible.

This also shows us the answer to your question: if the values are in separate indexes, as they are for regular indexes, then they won't affect each other's write throughput. On the other hand, if you have an index for a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) then it will have to updated for writes to each collection of that name and the throughput is affected for all those writes.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. And as to the second question, if I wanted to add a single-field index exemption for the documents in the `userChats` subcollection, would the scope need to be collection or collection-group?

Comment: I assume it would need to be a standard collection scope index exemption since there are no collection-group queries on this subcollection?

Comment: You need a collection group index when it contains data for all documents of all `userChats` collections in it, so if you want to query across all `userChats` at once.